# Could not find schema information for the element 'castle'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, web-config

I'm creating a Custom tag in my web.config. I first wrote the following entry under the **configSections** section.

```
<section name="castle"
           type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler,
         Castle.Windsor" />
```

But, when I try to create a **castle** node inside the **configuration** node as below

```
<castle>
    <components>
    </components>
</castle>
```

I get the following error message:"***Could not find schema information for the element '**castle**'***." "***Could not find schema information for the element '**components**'***."

Am I missing something? I can't find why. And, if I run the application anyway, I get the following error "***Could not find section 'Castle' in the configuration file associated with this domain.***"

Ps.// The sample comes from "Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework"/Steven Sanderson/APress ISBN-13 (pbk): 978-1-4302-1007-8" on page 99.

Thank you for the help

============================================================

Since I believe to have done exactly what's said in the book and did not succed, I ask the same question in different terms. ***How do I add a new node using the above information?***

=============================================================================

Thank you. I did what you said and do not have the two warnings. However, I've go a big new warning:

"The element '**configuration**' in namespace '**MyWindsorSchema**' has invalid child element '**configSections**' in namespace '**MyWindsorSchema**'. List of possible elements expected: '*include, properties, facilities, components' in namespace 'MyWindsorSchema*'."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is not an error that will prevent you from running your application. It is just a warning that Visual Studio emits because it does not know the `castle` node in a config file. You could use a schema to enable intellisense. Download the [Castle Windsor Schema](http://code.google.com/p/castlewindsorschema/) file and take a look at the readme.txt inside. It tells you to put `windsor.xsd` somewhere on your hard drive and then reference it in the config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="MyWindsorSchema"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="MyWindsorSchema file://S:\Common\Windsor\windsor.xsd">

    <configSections>
        <section name="castle" type="Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AppDomain.CastleSectionHandler, Castle.Windsor" />
    </configSections>

    <castle>
        <components>
        </components>
    </castle>
</configuration>
```